# Why execution time of this multi-threading program is so weird?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


interface ICounter {
    void inc();
    void dec();
    int get();
}


class Counter implements ICounter {
    protected int counter = 0;

    public void inc() { counter++; }
    public void dec() { counter--; }

    public int get() { return counter; }
}

class SynchronizedCounter extends Counter {
    public synchronized void inc() { counter++; }
    public synchronized void dec() { counter--; }
}

class BetterCounter implements ICounter {
    protected long up = 0;
    protected long down = 0;

    public void inc()  { up++; }
    public void dec()  { down--; }

    public int get() { return (int)(up + down); }
}


class SynchronizedBetterCounter extends BetterCounter {
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc() { synchronized(lock1) { up++; } }
    public void dec() { synchronized(lock2) { down--; }  }

}


class Inc extends Thread {
    ICounter i;

    public Inc(ICounter i) { this.i = i; }

    public void run() {
        for(int x = 0; x < 2147483647 ; x++) {
            i.inc();
        }
    }
}

class Dec extends Thread {
    ICounter i;

    public Dec(ICounter i) { this.i = i; }

    public void run() {
        for(int x = 0; x < 2147483647 ; x++) {
            i.dec();
        }
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ICounter[] c = {new Counter(), new SynchronizedCounter(), new BetterCounter(), new SynchronizedBetterCounter()};
        int numberOfCounters = 4;

        ArrayList<Inc> inc = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Dec> dec = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCounters; i++) {
            inc.add(new Inc(c[i]));
            dec.add(new Dec(c[i]));
        }

        long start = 0;
        long stop = 0;

        int returnVal[] = new int[4];
        long execTime[] = new long[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCounters; i++) {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            inc.get(i).start();
            dec.get(i).start();

            try {
                inc.get(i).join();
                dec.get(i).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }

            stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            returnVal[i] = c[i].get();
            execTime[i] = stop-start;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Counter: " + c[i].getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.println("Value of counter: " + returnVal[i]);
            System.out.println("Execution time: " + execTime[i] + " ms\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to make counter with methods `inc` to increase value and `dec` to decrease it. It's written in 4 ways - the basic, with synchronization, with 2 variables (1 to increase, 2 to decrease) and with 2 variables and synchronization. There are 2 classes `Inc` and `Dec` for multithreading.

I know there can be problems with this code, but the goal is just to add and subtract big number, just once, as fast as possible.

**Output**

```
Counter: Counter
Value of counter: 2061724420
Execution time: 141 ms

Counter: SynchronizedCounter
Value of counter: 0
Execution time: 174210 ms

Counter: BetterCounter
Value of counter: 0
Execution time: 39468 ms

Counter: SynchronizedBetterCounter
Value of counter: 0
Execution time: 52176 ms
```

**Question:**
Why first execution time is so small, comparing to the others?

Comment: synchronization is time-consuming. threads have to wait their turns to enter a critical section

Comment: although in this case there are no other threads to wait for, the additional time is required to check the locks for availability

Comment: Also note that the value of your non-synchronized counter is _wrong_.  Fast but broken disqualifies it in my book.  You should also check out atomic operations, which are designed to concurrently manipulate primitive types very efficiently. For example, [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html)

Comment: There indeed are some issues with the test. You might consider fixing them to focus on the actual case that confuses you (e.g. the `SynchronizedBetterCounter` uses two distinct locks - this does not achieve any real effect in this case). However, the crux is almost certainly in inlining. I mean, you didn't expect the loop to really be executed `MAX_VALUE` times, did you? In any case, the question is strongly related (or, considering that this about a "Counter", *nearly* a duplicate) of the one that I answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009487/3182664

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: Counter vs SynchronizedCounter is comparing executing ~800M perfectly predictable instructions in each thread, vs ~250000M instructions with cross-core synchronization.

I ran the code with `java -server  -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:CompileCommand=print,Inc.run -XX:+PrintCompilation  Main` and looked at the disassembly.

After some iterations, this is the bulk of `Inc::run` for the `Counter` case:

```
  0x00007fcdb12bc6c0: mov    %r9d,%r11d
  0x00007fcdb12bc6c3: add    %r8d,%r11d
  0x00007fcdb12bc6c6: mov    %r11d,%ecx
  0x00007fcdb12bc6c9: add    $0x10,%ecx
  0x00007fcdb12bc6cc: mov    %ecx,0xc(%r10)     ;*putfield counter
                                                ; - Counter::inc@7 (line 14)
                                                ; - Inc::run@12 (line 53)

  0x00007fcdb12bc6d0: add    $0x10,%r9d         ;*iinc
                                                ; - Inc::run@17 (line 52)

  0x00007fcdb12bc6d4: cmp    $0x7ffffff0,%r9d
  0x00007fcdb12bc6db: jl     0x00007fcdb12bc6c0  ;*if_icmpge
                                                ; - Inc::run@5 (line 52)
```

This is essentially equivalent to:

```
int value = i.counter;
for (; i<2147483632; i+=16) {
  value += 16;
  i.counter = value;
}
```

So in other words, it inlines the function, adds 16 on each iteration, and never bothers reading back the value.

For comparison, here is the 68 line `SynchronizedCounter.inc` method (see if you can spot the 3 lines that make up `counter++` itself):

```
  0x00007fb9f356a380: mov    %eax,-0x14000(%rsp)
  0x00007fb9f356a387: push   %rbp
  0x00007fb9f356a388: sub    $0x40,%rsp
  0x00007fb9f356a38c: lea    0x20(%rsp),%rdi
  0x00007fb9f356a391: mov    %rsi,0x8(%rdi)
  0x00007fb9f356a395: mov    (%rsi),%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a398: mov    %rax,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a39b: and    $0x7,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a39f: cmp    $0x5,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3a3: jne    0x00007fb9f356a42a
  0x00007fb9f356a3a9: mov    0x8(%rsi),%ebx
  0x00007fb9f356a3ac: shl    $0x3,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3b0: mov    0xa8(%rbx),%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3b7: or     %r15,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3ba: xor    %rax,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3bd: and    $0xffffffffffffff87,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3c1: je     0x00007fb9f356a452
  0x00007fb9f356a3c7: test   $0x7,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3ce: jne    0x00007fb9f356a417
  0x00007fb9f356a3d0: test   $0x300,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3d7: jne    0x00007fb9f356a3f6
  0x00007fb9f356a3d9: and    $0x37f,%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a3e0: mov    %rax,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3e3: or     %r15,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3e6: lock cmpxchg %rbx,(%rsi)
  0x00007fb9f356a3eb: jne    0x00007fb9f356a497
  0x00007fb9f356a3f1: jmpq   0x00007fb9f356a452
  0x00007fb9f356a3f6: mov    0x8(%rsi),%ebx
  0x00007fb9f356a3f9: shl    $0x3,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a3fd: mov    0xa8(%rbx),%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a404: or     %r15,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a407: lock cmpxchg %rbx,(%rsi)
  0x00007fb9f356a40c: jne    0x00007fb9f356a497
  0x00007fb9f356a412: jmpq   0x00007fb9f356a452
  0x00007fb9f356a417: mov    0x8(%rsi),%ebx
  0x00007fb9f356a41a: shl    $0x3,%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a41e: mov    0xa8(%rbx),%rbx
  0x00007fb9f356a425: lock cmpxchg %rbx,(%rsi)
  0x00007fb9f356a42a: mov    (%rsi),%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a42d: or     $0x1,%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a431: mov    %rax,(%rdi)
  0x00007fb9f356a434: lock cmpxchg %rdi,(%rsi)
  0x00007fb9f356a439: je     0x00007fb9f356a452
  0x00007fb9f356a43f: sub    %rsp,%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a442: and    $0xfffffffffffff007,%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a449: mov    %rax,(%rdi)
  0x00007fb9f356a44c: jne    0x00007fb9f356a497  ;*aload_0
                                                ; - SynchronizedCounter::inc@0 (line 21)

  0x00007fb9f356a452: mov    0xc(%rsi),%eax     ;*getfield counter
                                                ; - SynchronizedCounter::inc@2 (line 21)

  0x00007fb9f356a455: inc    %eax
  0x00007fb9f356a457: mov    %eax,0xc(%rsi)     ;*putfield counter
                                                ; - SynchronizedCounter::inc@7 (line 21)

  0x00007fb9f356a45a: lea    0x20(%rsp),%rax
  0x00007fb9f356a45f: mov    0x8(%rax),%rdi
  0x00007fb9f356a463: mov    (%rdi),%rsi
  0x00007fb9f356a466: and    $0x7,%rsi
  0x00007fb9f356a46a: cmp    $0x5,%rsi
  0x00007fb9f356a46e: je     0x00007fb9f356a48b
  0x00007fb9f356a474: mov    (%rax),%rsi
  0x00007fb9f356a477: test   %rsi,%rsi
  0x00007fb9f356a47a: je     0x00007fb9f356a48b
  0x00007fb9f356a480: lock cmpxchg %rsi,(%rdi)
  0x00007fb9f356a485: jne    0x00007fb9f356a4a7  ;*return
                                                ; - SynchronizedCounter::inc@10
```

In addition to this, there's a 93 line loop in `Inc::run` that invokes the above on each of its 2 billion iterations. Envelope calculations therefore suggest the `tl;dr` from the start of this post.

Answer (score 0):

This looks for optimization done by Java compiler: `for(int x = 0; x < 2147483647 ; x++) {i.inc()}` can be simplified to `i += 2147483647`.

Run your code without JIT (`-Djava.compiler=NONE`) and you will see the difference.

Comment: While this is almost certainly true (also, as of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56009487/3182664 , and assuming that this works across being called via an `interface`), it is a veeery handwaving answer. More details (beyond the guess) would be appreciated.